# Umbraco view Logs files

Tags: umbraco

I am new to Umbraco and I am trying to see the logs for Umbraco from the interface. I do not have any logs info under the developer menu. 
I am geeting an error like: 
error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object(see log for full details) and I can't see access point to logs file.

**Note** I have an admin user.

Where are the logs usually placed? Can I see them from the interface?
Where I can find log files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The log files are usually in the App_Data > Logs folder. You'll need to install a plugin to see them from the backend, one is [Diplo Trace Log Viewer](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/diplo-trace-log-viewer/)